# Why is a short exact sequence the same as a bicartesian square?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, group-homomorphism, exact-sequence, limits-colimits

Let $N \rightarrowtail G \twoheadrightarrow H$ be a sequence of group homomorphisms, with maps $\alpha: N \rightarrowtail G$ a monomorphism and $\beta: G \twoheadrightarrow H$ an epimorphism. I am wondering why the sequence is exact iff the following diagram with injective $\alpha$ and surjective $\beta$ is bicartesian, i.e. $N$ in the following is the limit and $H$ is the colimit with $\alpha$ injective and $\beta$ surjective:

\begin{array}{ccc}
N & \xrightarrow{\alpha} & G \\
\text{proj}\downarrow & & \downarrow\beta \\
1 & \hookrightarrow & H
\end{array}

I certainly get that the above diagram commutes implies that $\beta \circ \alpha = 1$, i.e. $\text{Im } \alpha \leq \ker \beta$. However, I am not sure how the fact that the square is bicartesian iff $\text{Im } \alpha = \ker \beta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\iota$ is the inclusion $\ker \beta \hookrightarrow G$, the diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\ker \beta @>\iota>> G \\
@VVV @VV{\beta}V \\
1 @>>> H
\end{CD}
$$
commutes.
Since $N$ is the limit, there is a map $\kappa \colon \ker \beta \to N$ such that
$$
\alpha \circ \kappa = \iota.
$$
Hence:
$$
\ker \beta = \iota(\ker \beta) = \alpha(\kappa(\ker \beta)) \leq \operatorname{im} \alpha.
$$